# Return names of tables in a case exists query

Tags: sql-server

I want to check if a specific value exists in some tables in my database:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 FROM ( 
    SELECT targetId FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table1] UNION 
    SELECT targetId FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table2] UNION 
    SELECT targetId FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table3] UNION 
    SELECT targetId FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table4] 
)T1 
WHERE T1.targetId = 'idToSearch') 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag ;
```

The above query returns `flag = 1` if the targetId `idToSearch` is found in these tables.

Is it possible to return also the names of the tables that this targetId was found? For example:

| flag | tableNames |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Table1, Table2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string aggregation instead of `EXISTS`.

> Note that generally `UNION ALL` is more efficient than `UNION`, although in an `EXISTS` this usually makes no difference

```sql
SELECT
  Flag = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  TableNames = STRING_AGG(TableName, ', ')
FROM
( 
    SELECT TableName = 'Table1', targetId
      FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Table2', targetId
      FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table2]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Table3', targetId
      FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table3]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Table4', targetId
      FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table4] 
) T1
WHERE T1.targetId = 'idToSearch';
```

Answer (score 1):

Organically you would just select the tables where that ID is found like this

```
SELECT tablename 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT targetId, 't1' as tablename FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table1] UNION 
    SELECT targetId, 't2' FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table2] UNION 
    SELECT targetId, 't3' FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table3] UNION 
    SELECT targetId, 't4' FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[Table4] 
) T1 
WHERE targetId = 'idToSearch'
```